# Should a change in the type of thrown exceptions be considered a breaking change?

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

If I have a public API that is being managed using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), should a change in the type of exceptions that a method may throw be considered a breaking change?

Consider this example:

```
// API version 1.0.0
public void Method()
{
     // this may throw ThirdPartyComponentException 
     _thirdPartyComponent.SomeMethod();
}
```

Calling code may look like this:

```
try
{
    _api.Method();
}
catch (ThirdPartyComponentException e)
{
    //some recovery logic
}
```

If the implementation of `API.Method` is changed thusly:

```
// API version ?.?.?
public void Method()
{
    try
    {
        // this may throw ThirdPartyComponentException 
        _thirdPartyComponent.SomeMethod();
    }
    catch (ThirdPartyComponentException e)
    {
        throw new MyApiException(e);
    }
}
```

should the semantic version major value be incremented because this change may be breaking? It certainly would break the exception handler above so seems like a breaking change.

Comment: If you're going to do this change, better make that change throughout (consolidating exceptions throughout) and then make it a breaking change (a big refactor).

Comment: @nneonneo agreed. The example is simplified. So if the only change of the big refactor was exception signatures, would you increment the major version?

Comment: An alternative is to throw a RuntimeException if you don't want to break the existing API signature (major revision). It really depends on the type of exception (severity) thrown, You need to consider the amount of refactoring code and level of existing dependency to the API

Comment: If you change the method signature you should increment the major version number because it breaks the old code. A minor revision otherwise (Re-throw a RuntimeException) which doesn't need to be specified in signature

Comment: @dkackman: I would. Anything that breaks existing code should get a major version bump. This also means you should think about whether this change alone merits making a new major version, or whether you should hold off on the version bump until you have more improvements to make.